# Android - How to listen to broadcast receiver unregistered?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an activity A.java which sends a broadcast and needs to wait for this broadcast unregistered then do something else. This broadcast receiver will invoke another activity B.java and only unregister the broadcast receiver when the activity is finished.

So my question is how to make A.java listen to the broadcastReceiver unregistered?

To be more specific, it's A.java in app A and B.java in app B.  I can't figure out a way to communicate between apps but broadcast. Does anyone have better idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: What you describe does not sound like the way Broadcast intents are meant to be used. Can you post some code to illustrate what you are doing and why you need to do it this way?

Comment: "So my question is how to make A.java listen to the broadcastReceiver unregistered?" It's impossible to listen on unregistered BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: See updated question description.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rethink your app flow. When Activity A sends a local broadcast, Activity B can listen and send back another broadcast after the task which it is supposed to do is done. You don't have to listen to Broadcast Receivers being unregistered, as you should be unregistering them in a lifecycle teardown event (such as onStop).

Comment: It's not communicating within app, it's actually one app sends to another app

Answer (score 0):

Wrong appraoch. You cannot be triggered on "unregister" of a receiver.

You can communicate between activities iun a single task either by calling `startActivityForResult()` or `startActivity()` and passing data in `Intent`, or by sending data in broadcast `Intent`s. Leave your receivers registered and listening, and send as many broadcast `Intent`s as necessary.